# How to change a globel variable in a usart interrupt(HAL)(stm32f407)

Tags: stm32

I want to use a bluetooth module to control the state of a led.I'm pretty sure that the program enter the interrupt because it can send back the character I send with a smart phone. However I also changed a global variable, LEDSTATE, in the code.But the state of LED didn't change and I found the variable remain unchanged with a watch window. I was confused. I tried to use the keyword volatile or extern but nothing changed.

```
volatile uint8_t LEDSTATE=1;
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    uint8_t k;
    UNUSED(huart);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)aRxBuffer,1,0xFFFF);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    LEDSTATE++;
    LEDSTATE=LEDSTATE%2;
    NUMMM++;
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, aRxBuffer, 1);
}
```

Comment: You mess with HAL API. `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` works in interrupt context. You can call `HAL_UART_Transmit` only in non-interrupt context, for ex. in `main()`. You can rise flag in `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`, read this flag in your main loop and use `HAL_UART_Transmit`

Comment: @StephenPlyaskin, please don't answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

I think you wanted to use HAL_GPIO_TogglePin instead, as in your current version of the code you always set the GPIO to 0.
If you change it to toggle you can get rid off LEDSTATE variable all together.
As to why you didn't see the variable change value, there are many possible reasons. Most probably it was optimized away, as it unused.

Btw. don't use blocking functions in IT, because they can mess with the normal operations of the main program. (Talking about blocking UART_TX.)